# Send list<AnonymousType> from controller to view in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, anonymous-types

Controller action method-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var todaysTarget = from ra in db.Employee ...
                       select new { ra.RaCode, ra.TargetQuantity };
    return View(todaysTarget.ToList());
}
```

Razor view-

```
@model List<object>


@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @:item.Name;
}
```

It gives me exception-

> this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'.

Any help?

Comment: This is a horrible idea.  The point of the view is to be specific to the model.  Don't use an anonymous type, just make the type.

Comment: Why would you use an anonymous type here?

Comment: If it is an attempt to make a Generic view which can be used to display supplied values, this is not a good solution to go with anonymous type. Even if you still need this type of functionality, i would suggest to use model type = List<string> OR List<KeyValuePair<string,string>  and always pass value.ToString() to the view if it is other than string.

If you don't need this to be a generic view, you must make it fixed type.

Answer (score 0):

Try in your view:

```
@model List<dynamic>
```

Or try in your return statement doing:

```
return View(todaysTarget.Cast<object>().ToList());
```

But if you do the latter, the item.Name statement will raise an error (type Object doesn't have a property of Name) which is why dynamic should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

This should work . I tried locally .

```
 @model IEnumerable<dynamic> 


<div>
<h1> Test</h1>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @item.Name;
}

</div>
```